# mongoose, schema validation failed despite valid data

Tags: mongoose

Using Node/Express/Mongoose

When I create a new document, I get a validation error during `create`

"Page validation failed: category: Path `category` is required., key: Path `key` is required., title: Path `title` is required."

But I confirmed that `data` is valid. What am I missing?

`data = {"title" : "ABC","key" : "DEF", "category" : "GHI"}`

Schema

```
let pageSchema = new Schema({
    title: {
    type: String,
    required: true
},
key: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true
},
category: {
    type: String,
    required: true
}
},
{
  timestamps: true
});
```

Method (Class loaded inside Model)

```
class Page {
    static async createPage(data) {
       try {
         let page = new Page(data);
         return await this.create(page);
       }
       catch (err) {
         throw (err);
       }
    }
    ...
}
pageSchema.loadClass(Page);
module.exports = mongoose.model('Page', pageSchema);
```

Comment: It looks like you can't instantiate a mongoose model with `new Page(data)`. You have to instantiate it with `new Page()` and then manually set each field. Seems tedious to me.

Comment: sorry, i should have added a constructor to make the original work